# Ensure that Kinetic code ALWAYS executes AFTER externally loading DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

I'm using [the Boxer library from www.formstone.it](http://formstone.it/components/boxer) to display a modal popup window over my HTML page. On triggering the modal window, HTML content gets loaded into the modal DIV from a file on my server. The Boxer code:

```
$(".boxer.boxer_object").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $obj = $('<div class="outer_container" />').load("http://www.myserver.com/game_modal.html",function(){

    setTimeout(function (){

        ... Kinetic code which loads several image and GUI elements for a simple game ...

    }, 2000); // delay Kinetic code execution with 2 seconds

    $.boxer($obj);

});
```

Even though it does seemingly only execute the KineticJS code AFTER the HTML code has loaded, I do still sporadically get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

As I understand it, this error occurs when the canvas is trying to target a DIV which does not yet exist. In other words, the KineticJS code executes AFTER the code has loaded but BEFORE the relevant container DIV has become part of the page structure.

As seen in my code above, I now use a setTimeout() function to delay the KineticJS code execution with 2 seconds. Even though less than ideal, I have not seen the error again, with the game graphics loading every time. However, this is a fix that may be working on my browser but which may fail for someone else in other conditions.

Is there a proper way in which to ensure that the KineticJS code will ALWAYS execute AFTER the externally loaded HTML code has become part of the page structure? i.e. after the container DIV which the KineticJS code targets for the HTML5 canvas actually exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to skip the ajax call and render the game's container and loading markup manually:

```
var $game = $('<div id="outside_container" style="text-align:center; width:900px; height=600px;"><span style="display:inline-block; line-height:600px; font-size: 4em;">LOADING...</span></div>');
```

Then use the 'callback' option to initialize the game:

```
$boxer($game, {
    callback: initGame
});

function initGame() {
    // kinetic js code
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! Testing shows the solution rock solid, with the DIV always ready before the script targets it. This solution uses Boxer's callback option to execute a function after the modal window has initialized. See Boxer webpage [link](http://formstone.it/components/boxer). In the initGame() function I then used jQuery getScript() to load and execute a JS file which holds the KineticJS game code (dynamically generated by the server). Thanks for all other answers, but I have too low rep power to vote for them.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  I haven't used boxer.

I took a quick peek at your boxer link.

There is a callback which executes "after opening instance".

How about putting your Kinetic code in that callback function you can supply to boxer.

Comment: I tried that also with similar sporadic errors. It would seem that completion of loading external HTML code does not guarantee the required DIV is part of the page structure in time.

Comment: Ouch!  OK, then you probably have to do the long-form of jquery ajax request and set the async property to false:  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you are trying to create a `div` with the class of 'outer_container' when the `onclick` event occurs. You then want to 'load' your game modal from your web service and then run the kinetic js and boxer code asynchronously (via the callback) when it has been returned.

Asynchronous functionality can always been a bit fiddly. In your asynchronous chain of events, I think creating the `div` at the same time as attaching a .load() function to it means that sometimes the web service may be ready before the `div` has been created.

Have you tried creating the `div`element before calling a web service pointing at that element?

You could either create the`div` when you first intialise the page or try this...

```
$(".boxer.boxer_object").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    //create the div first before the web service call to ensure it exists...

    var obj = document.createElement('div');
    obj.setAttribute('class', 'outer_container');

    $('.outer_container').load("http://www.myserver.com/game_modal.html",function(){

        //your code here, called after the web service has returned data...

        $.boxer(obj);

    });
```

I would personally just declare the 'outer_container' `div` before the declaration of the `onclick` event.

I hope this helps :).